# How to get number of week generated in a specific date range

Tags: mysql

I want to get all week generated in a specific date period.
i.e.
I have a table Event having start_date 2014-01-01 and end_date 2014-01-10 . If i said my week starts on Wednesday than the out put would be

```
 Start date  |  end date
 2014-01-01  |  2014-01-07
 2014-01-07  |  2014-01-10
```

Comment: you want to do a search??

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a SQL query. You may be able to do it in a stored procedure.

Comment: @user3064914 I want to get Week wise details as week start and end date from specific period(As i specified)

Comment: @Barmar Ok..Can u plz give some hint regarding SP